# Web API read JSON/ XML parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api2

I have web API and I want to read all the parameters passed to it in the "Request body". I'm posting data using Fiddler as shown below but I am not able to read these parameters in the controller:

[image: Fiddler Image]

Code in API controller looks like

```
public async Task<string> Post()
{
    return await Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}
```

Getting nothing in the response:

[image: Fiddler Response Image]

Not sure what's going wrong here, but can't read posted contents.

Comment: [Duplicate Question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12284558/1260204) (add `.Result`)

Comment: it didn't help me @Igor

Comment: When you say `not able to read parameters in controller`, did you put a breakpoint and try to debug the action? Was the action even being hit?

Answer (score 0):

I tested the following with Fiddler

```
POST http://localhost:35979/api/tests HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Fiddler
Host: localhost:35979
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 36

{"FirstName":"Foo","LastName":"Bar"}
```

Using this controller. (You did not provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so crafted my own)

```
[RoutePrefix("api/student")]
public class StudentController : ApiController {
    // POST api/student
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("")]
    public async Task<string> Post() {
        var content = await Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        return content;
    }
}
```

With a break point on `content` I was able to debug that the raw value posted was

```
"{\"FirstName\":\"Foo\",\"LastName\":\"Bar\"}"
```

which looked like this in the `Text Visualizer` in visual studio

```
{"FirstName":"Foo","LastName":"Bar"}
```

Back in Fiddler I received the following Raw response (Other headers removed for brevity)

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 46

"{\"FirstName\":\"Foo\",\"LastName\":\"Bar\"}"
```

You will notice the content posted was indeed returned in the response.

However it was returned as a raw escaped string. If you go to the JSON Tab of the response in Fiddler it will be empty like you showed in your caption. But you will notice a message at the bottom stating

> Invalid text at position 0

which was not visible in your caption. My guess is that Fiddler could not parse the content of the response as Json.

Now if it is you want the framework to consume the parameters sent to your controller you can try one the following.

Create a model/payload to store you parameters so you can work with objects instead of raw values.

```
public class Student {
    public string FirstName {get;set;}
    public string LastName {get;set;}
}
```

Edit your controller to either expect that model or as you will see in the second example action it can extract the parameters from the body or URI

```
[RoutePrefix("api/student")]
public class StudentController : ApiController {
    // POST api/student
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("")]
    public async Task<Student> Post(Student content) {
        var FirstName = content.FirstName;
        var LastName = content.LastName;
        return content;
    }

    // POST api/student/bodyexample
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("bodyexample")]
    public async Task<Student> Post2([FromBody]FirstName, [FromBody] LastName) {
        var content = new Student { FirstName = FirstName, LastName = LastName };
        return content;
    }

}
```

Hope this helps